# How to use python code remove txt line before string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Sample.txt file as below:

```
back
bold
yellow
green
country
code
bold
hello
yellow
country
code
bold
country
```

I wish to delete the first few line before **country**,so expected outcome is

```
country
code
bold
hello
yellow
country
code
bold
country
```

Anyone have ideas on this?

Comment: Did you try any code for this you can provide

Answer (score 1):

you can use [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to find out the position of `country` in the list, and then use slicing to get everything after it.

could you please try this, and let me know how it works for you?

```py
content = []
with open('Sample.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = content[content.index('country\n'):]

with open('Sample.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of lines in the file, use `index` to get the first occurrence of `'country'` and then slice the list.

```
with open('Sample.txt') as inpfile:
    lines = list(map(str.strip, inpfile.readlines()))
    print(len(lines))
    print(lines[lines.index('country'):])
```

Or you could loop over the file and only start storing the lines after you encounter country (this would avoid loading everything into a list first):

```
with open('Sample.txt') as inpfile:
    is_storing = False
    lines = []
    for l in inpfile:
        if not is_storing and l.strip() == 'country':
            is_storing = True

        if is_storing:
            lines.append(l.strip())

    print(lines)
```